# Swapping values in a sorted object map

Tags: c#, sorteddictionary

Lets say I have an sorted dictionary whose keys are objected

```
public class ExecutionMap 
{
    protected SortedDictionary<object, object> ExecutionMap { get; set; }
}
```

Lets say I lets say I have an object in that map and I want to swap its position with the the next :

```
public void SwapUp(object key) 
{
    
    value = ExecutionMap.Get(key);
    //How do I do I swap with the one that comes before it 
}
```

Whats an efficient way to swap this with the one before it?
I would prefer not to have to enumerate the dictionary to find the key before it

Comment: You can't. And it would be odd to do so as it needs to remain sorted. You might be better off with a sorted `List` and using `BinarySearch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `SortedDictionary<K,V>` you could use a `C5.TreeDictionary<K,V>` from the third-party [C5](https://github.com/sestoft/C5) library. This type offers rich functionality regarding finding previous and next entries, finding ranges of entries, supports backward enumeration etc. All these operations are implemented efficiently on top of a red-black tree set. Comparatively the functionality offered by the native [`SortedDictionary<K,V>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2) is rather poor, and it's not sufficient for implementing what you are trying to achieve.

```
public class ExecutionMap
{
    protected C5.TreeDictionary<object, object> ExecutionMap { get; set; }

    public void SwapUp(object key)
    {
        // Find the entry with this key
        if (ExecutionMap.Find(ref key, out var value))
        {
            // Find the entry that comes before it
            if (ExecutionMap.TryPredecessor(key, out var predecessor))
            {
                // Create a key that is smaller than the key of the predecessor
                // Creating a suitable key may be tricky
                var newKey = CreateSmallerKey(predecessor.Key);

                // Swap the key of the stored value
                // An exception will be thrown if the newKey already exists
                ExecutionMap.Add(newKey, value);
                bool removed = ExecutionMap.Remove(key);
                Debug.Assert(removed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was debating on using some third parties before but I didn't want to add the dependencies.   But seeing as this is more than efficient for the demands I'll accept

Comment: @johnny5 or you could wait Microsoft to enhance the `SortedDictionary<K,V>` with the missing functionality. But this may take years, and may never happen because of the cost. Anything that is made by Microsoft is [very expensive](https://ericlippert.com/2003/10/28/how-many-microsoft-employees-does-it-take-to-change-a-lightbulb/), because of the large number of people involved in the decision making, the tedious suggest/commit/approve process etc. It may cost more to Microsoft to make a decent `SortedDictionary`, than for someone else to write the whole C5 library from scratch.

Comment: No this will more than suffice for now,  I've been waiting for a lot of data-structures in .NET which probably won't make it in ever lol

Comment: @johnny5 at least after 6 years of requests, we will probably get a decent [`PriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43957 "Developers can use a built in PriorityQueue type") from Microsoft, hopefully with the next major .NET release. Yeah!  